# VideoView not streaming from https url in android 4.0(ICS)?

Tags: android, https, streaming, android-videoview

i have searching for the soultion to play a HTTPS video in android. i have come to know that https does not support for before 3.1 from [android media support doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#network). so i have tested it in the android 4.0.3 emulator. still i am getting the same error (Media player error (-1,243234242)).

But i have tested same video with HTTP. its working fine to me.

```
videoview.setContentURI(Uri.parse("https://url_that_i_am_using");
```

Any idea to play https video streaming in video view or any permission do i need to specify in my manifest/serverside/video encoding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Please give your suggestion on this. i am searching for this more than a week. thanks in advance

Comment: @yorkw: It starts downloading without asking for SSL certificate acceptance in default browser. but downloaded video is not playing in android 4.0. but its playing fine in 2.3. My doubt is about https url is start downloading the video in 2.3. why not its not supporting to videoview??? Any Idea?